# Is the language of sums of integers regular?

Tags: regular-languages

Over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,\ldots,9,/\}$, is the following language regular:

$$L=\left\{x/y/z:z=\mathrm{str}\bigl(\mathrm{int}(x)+\mathrm{int}(y)\bigr)\right\}$$

where $\mathrm{str}$ maps an integer to its decimal representation, and $\mathrm{int}$ does the opposite thing.

It contains $0/0/0$, $10/34/44$, $1/999/1000$ and so on. It is not an homework or something, I am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not regular. Consider the strings "$1^n/0/$" which must be followed by exactly n 1's. So with a finite state machine, after processing $1^n/0/$, we must be in a state $S_n$ which ends up in an accepting state if and only if we process exactly n further 1's. So for n ≠ n', the states $S_n$ and $S_{n'}$ are different, which means the finite state machine has an infinite number of states.

Comment: Thats a nice proof thank you